# FitNesse: Is it possible to extract information from the response of a test step, and use this value in the next test step

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am wondering that is there any possibility in FitNesse, while executing the test stages, to get a value from the response of a test stage and use this value in the next test stage.

I am using `hsac-fitnesse-fixtures` and SOAP web services.

For example, we have 3 test stages, and value from the response of the first stage can automatically transfer to the second stage to get the response of the second stage.

When comparing with SOAP UI we have property transfer.

Example below:

We have request XML:

```
!define POST_BODY_2 { {{{
    <ns1:ZIP>@{zip}</ns1:ZIP>
    </s11:Envelope>
}}} }
```

Stage 1:

```
|check|xPath|//weather:City/text()|@{City}|
```

And we get a response XML that contains the city name, as [here](http://fhoeben.github.io/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/examples-results/HsacExamples.SlimTests.HttpTests.HttpPost2UsingScenarioTest.html).

Is it possible to pass this city name as a value to the second test stage?

I.e we have another post XML request `!define POST_BODY_3` and to this request can we pass the value (city value) and have the next response XML.

Stage 2 test:

```
|check |response status|200|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SLiM as test system, you can use slim symbol

`$slimSymbol` is a "runtime variable" used in SLiM test system. They are defined by using `$slimSymbol=` symtax in the test case, and the value will only be available in the runtime. Documentation [here](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.SymbolsInTables)

---

In your case, you are using a decision table in the first test case. So instead of having only one output column, I guess you can do

```
#some setup here

| send request |
| zip | City? | City? |
| 10007 | New York | $response1= |
| 94102 | San Francisco | $response2= |
```

And in the later test case, you can refer to the city names using `$response1` and `$response2`. Note that there isn't `{}` around the variables.

Comment: Correct, so your 'stage one' becomes: `|$city=|xPath |//weather:City/text()|` you could than use `$city` as a value in a script or scenario.

Comment: How can I use the variable ? Can you elaborate it with an example. Thank you

Comment: @botguide see my edit. I don't have fitnesse handy at the moment, let me know how it works for you.

Comment: @FriedHoeben . I have given the  $city as a value in script for the nest test stage as below  !define POST_BODY_2 { 
      <ns1:ZIP>@{city}</ns1:ZIP>
   </s11:Envelope>
}}} }  and tried for  |show| response |  But I am getting an error as show: Bad table! DecisionTables should have at least three rows. , So I am not   able to check whether the value has been passed through $city.

Comment: @FriedHoeben . How can I use the variable in a script or scenario. Could you please give an example here. Thank you

Comment: @botguide just assign a value to it using '| $var= | some fixture method |' or like the syntax I posted above. and when you need it, refer to it as $var.

Comment: @XiaweiZhang . Actually I am trying to do the same without writing separate fixtures since I am using hsac-fitnesse-fixtures. Is there any possibilities. Thank you.

Comment: @botguide the sample shows assignment to a variable. If you had a variable containing a city name you would use it instead of for instance 'New York'. What are you looking for?

Comment: @FriedHoeben . Actually I am looking  to use the value of $city in the   next xml request (what I mean next text stage) inorder to get the intended xml response. So If i give variable $city in the next xml request I should get the intended xml response ie , xml request can read the value of variable $city from the previous xml request(First stage)  Thank you.

Comment: @botguide You could use $response1 as value for the zip column in row number 4 in example above (instead of 94102)...